# What does 0.5sigma mean?

Tags: self-study, normal-distribution, standard-deviation, quantiles

I want to ask about a term about "this data is within 0.5 sigma". If I understand correctly the person first calculates standart deviation(sigma) of his data and multiples his/her std deviation with 0.5 and excludes those data points outside of this 0.5*std_data value. Is this correct?

And maybe is this 0.5sigma range also related to quantile range (say the range between 0.05 and 0.95 quantile of the data)

which one is correct? maybe I'm all wrong:)

Comment: The standard deviation is a statistic that measures the dispersion of a dataset relative to its mean... So, it provides information about the variability, how spread out are the values.

Comment: @Pitouille thanks. So I should be multiplying the standart deviation of data with 0.5 to find out if the given point is in the range of 0.5*sigma ?

Comment: Yes, if you want to determine how far your data point is away from the mean, talking in terms standard deviations can give you insights.

Comment: Are you sure you mean 0.5 sigma and not 5.0 sigma? "Five sigma" is a term commonly used.

Comment: @HarveyMotulsky Six sigma?

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely common to talk about how many standard deviations a point is from the mean. Without a reference point (such as the mean), a phrase like "within the range of 0.5*sigma" lacks meaning, but because of how common it is for the mean to be this reference, that seems like a safe assumption here.

Thus, it seems like what you want to do is deterine the interval $\mu\pm0.5\sigma$.

You know how to calculate means. You know how to calculate standard deviations. You know how to multiply by $0.5$. You know how to add and subtract.

That's all there is to it!

For example, if the mean is $9$ and standard deviation is $6$, you are looking at an interval of $9\pm3$, so $(6, 12)$.

(There is a technical point that you are, most likely, working with estimates, so it may be more appropriate to write $\bar x$ as an estimate of $\mu$ and $s$ as an estimate of $\sigma$.)